# Two HTML syntax Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3, sublimelinter

I have two HTML syntax on Sublime Text 3.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcxoM.png - screenshot

Plugins:

- Emmet
- Plugin Control
- SublimeLinter
- SublimeLinter-php
- SublimeCodeIntel
- SFTP
- PyV8

If all plugins enabled - https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyqTe.png

Windows 8.1 x86

How fix it?

Comment: Welcome! Please take a look at the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I agree with moffeltje

Comment: I'm Russian, learning english, sometimes. Sorry about that.